# How to put label inside input and make alwas visible

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

I need to do input like this, and word "seconds" should always stay visible and 
unchangeable. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

No JavaScripting needed here,

```css
.round {
  border:1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 4px; 
  padding: 8px;
}

.round input {
  border:0px solid black;
  width: 40px;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.round label {
  color: grey;
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="round">
  <label><input type="text">seconds</input></label>
</div>
</div>
```

[HTMLDog's CSS tutorial](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/beginner/) is a great one to follow.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#test{
width:100px;
  border:1px solid #E0E0E0;
  display:inline-block;
    border-radius: 5px; 
  border-top:1px solid #BBDEFB;

}
input{
width:25px;
  float:left;
  border:none;
}
label{
  color:#BDBDBD
}
input:focus{
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Seconds</label>
  </div>
  </div>
```